# UIViewController: detecting when view appears again

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController class that contains a WKWebView and implements WKNavigationDelegate.

I would like to detect when a the view controller appears again. I understand the method loadView but, if I push a new view on the stack and then go back from that view to the previous view (my view controller) which method is called on the view controller?

Comment: When you say "push a new view" are you referring to something like `[self.view addSubview:newView];` or do you mean `[self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController];` ? If you're pushing a new view controller then went back, the first view controller's `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` will trigger again. If you're referring to showing a subview on top of your view controller's view, then you may choose to use something like protocol whereby you define a `customViewDidPressClose:` delegate method then your view controller can implement that delegate method to get notified.

Answer (score 0):

The method that will be called is `viewWillAppear:`.

Answer (score 0):

If you push to next view then **viewDidLoad** will be called first

Then **viewWillAppear**, **viewDidAppea**r

If you pop to previous screen again (your UIViewController) then

**viewWillAppear** will be called first and after entire view appears

then **viewDidAppear** will be called..

**viewDidAppear** is useful in the cases where any method called at **viewWillAppear** after that you can Load the data at **ViewDidAppear**..

Answer (score 0):

The ViewControllers viewDidLoad method is only called once when the view is created for the first time.

```
// viewDidLoad is called only once when the view is created for the first time
 - (void) viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     // do your code here
}
```

You can also implement the below two methods in side your `ViewController.m` class

```
// viewWillAppear is called just before the view is about to be appeared
- (void) viewWillAppear
{
     [super viewWillAppear];
     // do your code here
}

// is called when the view has appeared
- (void) viewDidAppear
{
     [super viewDidAppear];
     // do your code here
}
```